# Ongoing event in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, events

Using tkinter, can I bind an ongoing event to activate while the mainloop still goes off?
Means it executes the same command over and over until the program is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `root.after` to run a function repeatedly like so:

```py
def repeat_task():
    # do stuff
    root.after(10, repeat_task)
```

this will constantly do something, and then run itself. the delay time shouldn't be 0 because it may not let tkinter's event loop process other events and will freeze. it will go until the window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `threading` approach:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

def myLoop():
    print("Hey I am looping!")
    threading.Timer(1, myLoop).start()

window = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(window, text = 'Threading', command = lambda: threading.Timer(1, myLoop).start()) 
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

- `threading.Timer` is an object that will run parallel to your GUI so it won't freeze it.
- `threading.Timer` will fire up every Nth second that you can specify in the constructor.

Comment: Very helpful method. Appreciated!